# Change GMSMapView default map background color in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

The GMSMapView in iOS has a default background color of tan, or something like it.

I have a requirement to change that color to white. I've tried using a subclass of GMSTileLayer without success (or errors). I need to place custom map overlays with white backgrounds onto the map view. In areas without the overlays, the base map color needs to match (white).

Tried the following without any luck:

```
[mapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Can anyone offer suggestions, or point me to a resource (other than Google) that might help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can only change the [mapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_types) of your `mapView`, otherwise you have to use the `GMSTIleLayer`. Currently, you can not change the color of the `mapView` with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can change GMSMapStyle of you map (available with Google Maps SDK for iOS 2.1). 
Styling works only on the kGMSTypeNormal map type. 
I create my own style with https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As of release 8.3.0 ([release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/release-notes)), it is possible to override the default map background color by using the [backgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/configure-map#configure_background_color) property that can be set on the [GMSMapViewOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view_options) object.

The documentation for the `backgroundColor` property states

> Specifies the background color of the map view, which displays whenever the map tiles are not fully loaded.

It could look like this:

```swift
let options = GMSMapViewOptions()
options.backgroundColor = .red
let mapView = GMSMapView(options: options)
```