# I can not change background color of Google Map MapType=kGMSTypeNone (SDK for IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

My map type is kGMSTypeNone.I add overlay on map. Default background color is gray. I want to assign transparent background but i did not succeed.

```
mapview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Is it possible to change background ?

Comment: As the comment in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106448/change-gmsmapview-default-map-background-color-in-ios) mentions, I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change GMSMapView default map background color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106448/change-gmsmapview-default-map-background-color-in-ios)