# Want to change background of google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

I Want to change the background to the white of google map but I could not change it. So, anybody know about any detail for this please provide me. If it is possible then give me a hint or code. Else give me a proper suggestion.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106448/change-gmsmapview-default-map-background-color-in-ios

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik :  Thank you. Your comment helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

let kMapStyle = "[" +
"  {" +
"    \"featureType\": \"poi.business\"," +
"    \"elementType\": \"all\"," +
"    \"stylers\": [" +
"      {" +
"        \"visibility\": \"off\"" +
"      }" +
"    ]" +
"  }," +
"  {" +
"    \"featureType\": \"transit\"," +
"    \"elementType\": \"labels.icon\"," +
"    \"stylers\": [" +
"      {" +
"        \"visibility\": \"off\"" +
"      }" +
"    ]" +
"  }" +
"]"
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Set the status bar style to complement night-mode.
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
  }

  override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 14.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

    do {
      // Set the map style by passing a valid JSON string.
      mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(jsonString: kMapStyle)
    } catch {
      NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }

    self.view = mapView
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create your custom style here...

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

- create your style and click on finish
- you get json format text and paste it in your code.

you can refer @Dhiraj Kumar answer for where to paste in code.