# iOS GMSMapView change initial loading background color

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106448/change-gmsmapview-default-map-background-color-in-ios) which might be the exact same problem but the accepted answer did not work for me.

We are currently using the Google Maps API to load a map to cover the entire view. The initial GMSMapView background color is something like a tan color, RGB(237, 234, 226), at least in xcode's view hierarchy but our application has a black background everywhere else so we get a flicker of tan before Google Maps loads our custom dark styles.

Does anyone know how to change the initial tan background color?

We are loading our custom styles in viewDidLoad (code below) but we assume the initial background will not be affected by this.

```
do {
  if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GoogleMapsStyle", withExtension: "json") {
    mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
  } else {
    NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
  }
} catch {
  NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
}
```

---

*Additional information that might be helpful:

The full page mapview is the primary part of a [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) view.

[image]

The full page mapview is triggered by a tap on a section of a table view cell which loads the PulleyView and the two container views (primary and drawer) within it, the primary view or full mapview and the drawer / "pulley" which contains a search bar and results.

During this tap functionality it takes the user's address that is accessible from the table view and sets the map's camera on the primary pulley container view and fills in the drawer pulley container view's search bar.

```
guard let pulleyVC = UIStoryboard(name: "EditAddress", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scheduleAddress") as? PulleyViewController else {
    log.error(formatLog("profile", "EditAddress failed to instantiate from storyboard"))
    return
}
pulleyVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
pulleyVC.addNavBar()
pulleyVC.setNavBarTitle(title: NSLocalizedString("editAddress", comment: ""))

guard let primaryContentVC = pulleyVC.primaryContentViewController as? PrimaryContentViewController else {
    log.error(formatLog("profile", "EditAddress failed to instantiate from storyboard"))
    return
}
if let placemark = userSelectedPlacemark {
    primaryContentVC.setMapLocation(delegate: self, placemark)
}
primaryContentViewController = primaryContentVC

guard let drawerContentVC = pulleyVC.drawerContentViewController as? DrawerContentViewController else {
    log.error(formatLog("profile", "EditAddress failed to instantiate from storyboard"))
    return
}
if let address = userSelectedPlacemark?.name {
    drawerContentVC.setMapPostalAddress(delegate: self, address, usersLocation: locationManager.location)
}
navController.pushViewController(pulleyVC, animated: true)
```

The custom json styles are loaded during the viewDidLoad function in the view controller for the PulleyView controller's primary view controller.

---

The primary content view controller's setMapLocation function is where we allocate mapview. Most of this function is actually setting up the marker. mapview is a global variable within this controller `@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!`.

```
func setMapLocation(delegate: PrimaryContentViewControllerDelegate?, _ placemark: CLPlacemark?) {
    if let delegate = delegate {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    guard let coordinate = placemark?.location?.coordinate else {
        log.warning(formatLog("map", "location not available"))
        return
    }
    savedPlacemark = placemark
    mapView.clear()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15.0)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)

    // REFACTOR THIS (ALSO IN MAPTABBLEVIEWCELL)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: camera.target)
    let markerImage = UIImage(named: "marker")
    let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)
    marker.iconView = markerView
    marker.map = mapView
    marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    // TODO: get this working and reusable (i.e. an extension?)
    let pulseMarker = GMSMarker(position: camera.target)

    let pulseRingImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pulse"))
    pulseRingImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(3.5)

    //transform scale animation
    var theAnimation: CABasicAnimation?
    theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
    theAnimation?.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    theAnimation?.autoreverses = false
    theAnimation?.fromValue = Float(0.5)
    theAnimation?.toValue = Float(1.0)
    theAnimation?.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    pulseRingImg.layer.add(theAnimation!, forKey: "pulse")
    pulseRingImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {() -> Void in
        //alpha Animation for the image
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        animation.duration = 3.5
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animation.values = [Float(2.0), Float(0.5)]
        pulseMarker.iconView?.layer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
    pulseMarker.iconView = pulseRingImg
    pulseMarker.layer.addSublayer(pulseRingImg.layer)
    pulseMarker.map = mapView
    pulseMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}
```

Comment: where do you allocate the mapview? allocate and set its style in the same method maybe!?

Comment: @Daij-Djan I added more details and a little bit more code. Sorry if its too wordy.

Comment: so the view is from storyboard? .. this doesnt show the allocation of the map but more (almost) never hurts! :)

Comment: sorry @Daij-Djan! Thank you for being patient. I added the setMapLocation function which is where we are initially settings the map's camera.

Comment: where is mapView set. Or is it a IBoutlet

Comment: it is an iboutlet. I included that in the details about the setMapLocation function code

Comment: @T.Okahara Did you manage to solve it? I'm having a problem with dark style on SDK v6.x: when moving the map first white background is shown and then dark tiles are loaded, which looks like blinking. Works fine on GoogleMaps v 5.36

Comment: I still see the white background. Any solutions?

Comment: @iOSUnit we did not fix it. 
I’m changed companies a few years ago but we left it as is.